# Combine Columns with Similar Column Names / Similar Column Strings - Reprex

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce, data-wrangling

**Goals:** To merge multiple columns just based on the similarity of the column name.

**Issues:** I am dealing with a large data set where the column names are replicated and look like this: wk1.1, wk1.2, wk1.3. For each row, there will be only one value in the similar column names, and the others will be NA. Coalesce is very helpful, but becomes tedious (messes up automation) when I have to list each column name. Is there a way to coalesce based off a string of characters? For instance below, I would prefer to coalesce %in% "wk1."

```
library(dplyr)
wk1.1 <- c(15, 4, 1)
wk1.2 <- c(3, 20, 4)
wk1.3 <- c(1, 2, 17)

df <- data.frame(wk1.1, wk1.2, wk1.3)
df[df < 14] <- NA
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(wk1 = coalesce(df$wk1.1, df$wk1.2, df$wk1.3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use splice it with `!!!`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      mutate(wk1 = coalesce(!!! .))
#  wk1.1 wk1.2 wk1.3 wk1
#1    15    NA    NA  15
#2    NA    20    NA  20
#3    NA    NA    17  17
```

---

Or another option is to `reduce` and apply `coalesce`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(wk1 = reduce(., coalesce))
```

Comment: You are the best @akrun ! Thank you as always for your in depth knowledge. 

This definitely worked on my reprex, but it is giving me issues in character vectors. Would you do anything different for a character vector?

Comment: @DonnyDolio thanks, I can think of `NA` being `"NA"` and thus not matching??  Can you please use `dput` to show a small example so that I get the structure of the data

Comment: sorry to leave you hanging. I really appreciate your help. Here is a dput of a small line of my code:


`structure(list(wk9 = c(NA, "W 56-35", "L 20-45", NA, "W 42-41", 
"W 41-38"), wk9.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "L 31-34", NA, NA), wk9.2 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
> `

Comment: @DonnyDolio thanks.  It is actually working for me.  I used `dplyr 1.0.0` `df %>% mutate(wk1 = coalesce(!!! .)) %>% pull(wk1)#
[1] NA        "W 56-35" "L 20-45" "L 31-34" "W 42-41" "W 41-38"`. The first is NA because all the values are NA in that row

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Your help is always appreciated @akrun . I think I am running into issues bc I used a web scrape and haven't cleaned up the data. I get 'argument must be a factor object, not a character vector.' I will clean up the data and see if this fixes the issue moving forward. Thanks for sharing your knowledge on how to combine similar column names!

Comment: @DonnyDolio in that case, can you change the columns to `character` i.e. `df %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character), wk1 = coalesce(!!! .))`

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the in-depth knowledge @akrun . Just a great reminder of all the heavy lifting you can do with dplyr